# Stream decompression of bz2 file from hadoop to python

Tags: python, hadoop

Can you decompress a BZ2 file on the fly line by line through hadoop?  Currently, I am doing this for local files

```
file = bz2.BZ2File(file_loc)
for l in file.readlines():
    print(l)
```

Would it be possible to do this while accessing a file in a hadoop file system?